# My script doesn't seems to go to the next pages and doesn't scrape all the data I would like

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here's my script (I didn't put all the code for the sake of clarity but I will explained in details some aspect) :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time   
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select    
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait     
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By     
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC   
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#chemin du folder ou vous avez placer votre chromedriver
PATH = "driver\chromedriver.exe"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1200,900")
options.add_argument('enable-logging')

j = 3
for url, name in zip(urlfinal, nameshotel) :

    commspos = []
    commsneg = []
    header = []
    notes = []
    dates = []
    datestostay = []

    driver.get(url)

    results = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

    reviews = soup.find_all('li', class_ = "review_list_new_item_block")

    for k in range(j): #iterate over n pages


        for review in reviews:
            try:
                commpos  = review.find("div", class_  = "c-review__row").text[11:].strip()
            except:
                commpos = 'NA'

            commspos.append(commpos)



            try:
                commneg  = review.find("div", class_  = "c-review__row lalala").text[17:].strip()
            except:
                commneg = 'NA'

            commsneg.append(commneg)


            #head = review.find('div', class_ = ' c-review-block__title c-review__title--ltr  ').text.strip()
            #header.append(head)


            note = review.find('div', class_ = 'bui-review-score__badge').text.strip()
            notes.append(note)


            date = review.find('span', class_ = 'c-review-block__date').text.strip()
            dates.append(date)


            try:
                datestay = review.find('ul', class_ = 'bui-list bui-list--text bui-list--icon bui_font_caption c-review-block__row c-review-block__stay-date').text[16:].strip()
                datestostay.append(datestay)
            except:
                datestostay.append('NaN')

            time.sleep(3)

        nextpages = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="pagenext"]')

        urlnext = nextpages.get_attribute("href")

        results2 = requests.get(urlnext)

        driver.get(urlnext)

        time.sleep(3)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(results2.text, "html.parser")

        reviews = soup.find_all('li', class_ = "review_list_new_item_block")


    data = pd.DataFrame({
        'commspos' : commspos,
        'commsneg' : commsneg,
        #'headers' : header,
        'notes' : notes,
        'dates' : dates,
        'datestostay' : datestostay,
        })

    data.to_csv(f"{name}.csv", sep=';', index=False, encoding = 'utf_8_sig')
    #data.to_csv(f"{name} + datetime.now().strftime("_%Y_%m_%d-%I_%M_%S").csv", sep=';', index=False)

    time.sleep(3)
```

A list of hotel links is stored in `urlfinal` like this one for example : [link](https://www.booking.com/reviewlist.fr.html?cc1=fr&dist=1&pagename=hotelistria&type=total&offset=0&rows=20)

And `nameshotel` is just a list of name and this list is used just for creation of csv files, doesn't matter too much.

I cannot figure it out why but this part doesn't seems to work :

```
nextpages = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="pagenext"]')

urlnext = nextpages.get_attribute("href")

results2 = requests.get(urlnext)

driver.get(urlnext)

time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(results2.text, "html.parser")

reviews = soup.find_all('li', class_ = "review_list_new_item_block")
```

My script scrape only 20 comments, for each links, there are 25 comments in each pages :

[image: output]

Yet, it seems that this `href` go to the next pages and I implemented this href into a loop as you can see above :

[image: nextpage]

Any ideas why it doesn't work as intended ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your URL part row=25 get all rows in HTML

```
import requests
headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"}
res=requests.get("https://www.booking.com/reviewlist.fr.html?cc1=fr&dist=1&pagename=hotelistria&type=total&offset=0&rows=25",headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

reviews = soup.find_all('li', class_ = "review_list_new_item_block")
```

Output:

```
len(reviews)

25
```

Above code is for one but below code is for 61 pages for that i have find out first page and last page `offset` value and based on that it extract reviews

```
import requests



def find_page_val():
    headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"}
    res=requests.get(f"https://www.booking.com/reviewlist.fr.html?cc1=fr&dist=1&pagename=hotelistria&type=total&offset=0&rows=25",headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    first=int(soup.find("div", class_="bui-pagination__pages").find_all("div",class_="bui-pagination__item")[1].find("a")['href'].split("=")[-1])
    last=int(soup.find("div", class_="bui-pagination__pages").find_all("div",class_="bui-pagination__item")[-1].find("a")['href'].split("=")[-1])
    total=first+last
    return first,total
    
def connection(i):
    headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"}
    res=requests.get(f"https://www.booking.com/reviewlist.fr.html?cc1=fr&dist=1&pagename=hotelistria&type=total&offset={i}&rows=25",headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    return soup


def get_list_reviews():
    first,total=find_page_val()
    for i in range(0,total,first):
        soup=connection(i)
        reviews =soup.find_all('li', class_ = "review_list_new_item_block")
        print(len(reviews))
```

in last call `get_list_reviews()` this function it gives ouptut

Output:

```
25
25
25
...
```

Comment: That doesn't seems to work. I cannot ifind how to incorporate this to scrape all the pages

Comment: i think it will work just put your code inside `get_list_reviews`  btw what you are finding in reviews like... sorry i got it wait i will update my answer

Comment: It run since forever but maybe it's normal

Comment: None, I obtained just 25 rows

Comment: so you want to find text from it or what please mention!

Comment: I want to scrape all the comments from all the pages