# xPath doesn't seems to go to the next pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here's my script :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait     
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By     
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = "driver\chromedriver.exe"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1200,900")
options.add_argument('enable-logging')
url = 'https://www.booking.com/index.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DCA0oTUIMZWx5c2Vlc3VuaW9uSA1YBGhNiAEBmAENuAEXyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAL_5ZqEBsACAdICJDcxYjgyZmI2LTFlYWQtNGZjOS04Y2U2LTkwNTQyZjI5OWY1YtgCBOACAQ&sid=303509179a2849df63e4d1e5bc1ab1e3&srpvid=e6ae6d1417bd00a1&click_from_logo=1'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=PATH)

driver.get('https://www.booking.com/index.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DCA0oTUIMZWx5c2Vlc3VuaW9uSA1YBGhNiAEBmAENuAEXyAEM2AED6AEB-AECiAIBqAIDuAL_5ZqEBsACAdICJDcxYjgyZmI2LTFlYWQtNGZjOS04Y2U2LTkwNTQyZjI5OWY1YtgCBOACAQ&sid=303509179a2849df63e4d1e5bc1ab1e3&srpvid=e6ae6d1417bd00a1&click_from_logo=1')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'}


cookie = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')
try:
    cookie.click()
except:
    pass

time.sleep(2)



job_title = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ss"]')
job_title.click()
job_title.send_keys('Paris') #ici on renseigne la ville, attention à la syntaxe
time.sleep(3)

search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="frm"]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/button')
search.click()
time.sleep(6)

linksfinal = []

n = 1 #le nombre de pages que vous voulez parcourir

for x in range(n): #iterate over n pages

    time.sleep(3)

    my_elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="js-sr-hotel-link hotel_name_link url"]')

    links = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in my_elems]

    links = [link.replace('\n','') for link in links]

    linksfinal = linksfinal + links

    time.sleep(3) 

    next = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="bk-icon -iconset-navarrow_right bui-pagination__icon"]')
      
    next.click()

#print(linksfinal)
nameshotel = []
for url in linksfinal:
    results = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")
    name = soup.find("h2",attrs={"id":"hp_hotel_name"}).text.strip("\n").split("\n")[1]
    nameshotel.append(name)


#linksfinal = ['https://www.booking.com/hotel/fr/d-argentine.fr.html?label=gen173nr-1DEgdyZXZpZXdzKIICOOgHSDNYBGhNiAEBmAENuAEXyAEM2AED6AEBiAIBqAIDuAKr2vuGBsACAdICJDE1YjBlZDY1LTI2NzEtNGM3Mi04OWQ1LWE5MjQ3OWFmNzE2NtgCBOACAQ;sid=303509179a2849df63e4d1e5bc1ab1e3;dest_id=-1456928;dest_type=city;dist=0;group_adults=2;group_children=0;hapos=1;hpos=1;no_rooms=1;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;sr_order=popularity;srepoch=1625662317;srpvid=b3d45a76bf450049;type=total;ucfs=1&#tab-main']

for i in range(len(linksfinal)) :
    linksfinal[i] = linksfinal[i].split("fr")[1]
    linksfinal[i] = linksfinal[i][1:]
    linksfinal[i] = linksfinal[i][:-1]

urlfinal = []
for i in range(len(linksfinal)) :
    urlfinal.append('https://www.booking.com/reviewlist.fr.html?cc1=fr&dist=1&pagename=' + str(linksfinal[i]) + '&type=total&offset=0&rows=25')

j = 3

for url, name in zip(urlfinal, nameshotel) :

    commspos = []
    commsneg = []
    header = []
    notes = []
    dates = []
    datestostay = []

    driver.get(url)

    results = requests.get(url, headers = headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

    reviews = soup.find_all('li', class_ = "review_list_new_item_block")

    for k in range(j): #iterate over n pages
   
        for review in reviews:
            try:
                commpos  = review.find("div", class_  = "c-review__row").text[11:].strip()
            except:
                commpos = 'NA'

            commspos.append(commpos)

            try:
                commneg  = review.find("div", class_  = "c-review__row lalala").text[17:].strip()
            except:
                commneg = 'NA'

            commsneg.append(commneg)
  
            note = review.find('div', class_ = 'bui-review-score__badge').text.strip()
            notes.append(note)

            date = review.find('span', class_ = 'c-review-block__date').text.strip()
            dates.append(date)

            try:
                datestay = review.find('ul', class_ = 'bui-list bui-list--text bui-list--icon bui_font_caption c-review-block__row c-review-block__stay-date').text[16:].strip()
                datestostay.append(datestay)
            except:
                datestostay.append('NaN')

            time.sleep(3)

        nextpages = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="pagenext"]')

        urlnext = nextpages.get_attribute("href")

        results2 = requests.get(urlnext)

        driver.get(urlnext)

        time.sleep(3)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(results2.text, "html.parser")

        reviews = soup.find_all('li', class_ = "review_list_new_item_block")


    data = pd.DataFrame({
        'commspos' : commspos,
        'commsneg' : commsneg,
        'notes' : notes,
        'dates' : dates,
        'datestostay' : datestostay,
        })

    data.to_csv(f"{name}.csv", sep=';', index=False, encoding = 'utf_8_sig')

    time.sleep(3)
```

I cannot figure it out why but the part where I tell the script to go to the next page doesn't seems to work :

```
nextpages = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="pagenext"]')

urlnext = nextpages.get_attribute("href")

results2 = requests.get(urlnext)

driver.get(urlnext)

time.sleep(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(results2.text, "html.parser")

reviews = soup.find_all('li', class_ = "review_list_new_item_block")
```

My script scrape only 25 comments, for each links, there are 25 comments in each pages, so it seems it scrapes only one pag while it should b scraping 3 pages there :

[image: output]

Yet, when I looked into th source code, it seems that this `href` go to the next pages. Hence, I implemented this href into a loop as you can see above :

[image: nextpage]

Any ideas why it doesn't work as intended ?

Comment: I have already post my answer on Author's old question which was same as above and you need put just what data you want from URL logic inside function here is the [link of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68361105/11583070)

Comment: [edit] your question and include at least 2 urls. also please highlight what you would like to extract.

Comment: I edited my post, I put all my script. I thought if I just put one part it would be more clear. It appears I was wrong, my bad

Answer (score 0):

If clicking or finding pagenext is not working for you then just change url. I had found that `offset=` is changing while you are going to next page. So. If your scraper scrape first page then change `offset=0` to `offset=10` then it is going to give you data from next page. Or run loop upto wherever you want to scrape data and increase offset by 10.

Here's example:

```
https://www.booking.com/reviewlist.fr.html?cc1=fr&dist=1&pagename=hotelistria&type=total&offset=0&rows=20
```

This is for first page and if we change `offset=10` the it gives us data from next page like:

```
https://www.booking.com/reviewlist.fr.html?cc1=fr&dist=1&pagename=hotelistria&type=total&offset=10&rows=20
```

You can do for loop like this:

```
for i in range(0,<up to you want>,10):
    url=f"https://www.booking.com/reviewlist.fr.html?cc1=fr&dist=1&pagename=hotelistria&type=total&offset={i}&rows=20"
```

If any further queries ask in comment.

Comment: Yeah I thought of this kind of solution but I have an list of url and I cannot see how to implement that for multiple url

Comment: What do you mean by _list of url_? Can you explain a little bit with example!

Comment: I created a list of hotels url with the help of scraping, so it's kind of hard to implement. With one url, it's easy, but with 60 it's harder (for me).

Comment: Because in my loop, it's named `url`, so how to change the offset based on that ? I hope i'm clear

Comment: Not complete clear, but I understand what you are talking about. If I can help you I will edit my answer and tell you!

Comment: Yeah it's kind of hard to explain in a context like that.Thank you !

Comment: Doesn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68361105/11583070) exactly answer your question!

Comment: It seems it doesn't work, I obtained 25 comments as before